# show that MSE$(\hat{\theta}) = E[(\hat{\theta} − θ)^2] = V(\hat{\theta}) + (B(\hat{\theta}))^2$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Using the identity
$(\hat{\theta} − θ) = [\hat{\theta} − E(\hat{\theta})] + [E(\hat{\theta}) − θ] = [\hat{\theta} − E(\hat{\theta})] + B(\hat{\theta})$,

I need to show that MSE$(\hat{\theta}) = E[(\hat{\theta} − θ)^2] = V(\hat{\theta}) + (B(\hat{\theta}))^2$.

I got MSE$(\hat{\theta}) = E[(\hat{\theta} − θ)^2] = E[([(\hat{\theta}-E(\hat{\theta})]+[E(\hat{\theta})-{\theta}])^2] = E[([\hat{\theta} - E(\hat{\theta})] + B(\hat{\theta}))^2] = E[[\hat{\theta} - E(\hat{\theta})]^2+2B(\hat{\theta})[\hat{\theta}-E(\hat{\theta})]+B(\hat{\theta})^2] = E[[\hat{\theta} - E(\hat{\theta})]^2+2(E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta)E[\hat{\theta}-E(\hat{\theta})]+E[(E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta)^2] $

I am struct here. Can anyone help

Answer (score 6):

It's really a **lot** simpler than that.  I would begin with the RHS instead:  $$\begin{align*} {\rm Var}[\hat \theta] + {\rm Bias}[\hat\theta]^2 &= {\rm E}[\hat \theta^2] - {\rm E}[\hat \theta]^2 + ({\rm E}[\hat \theta] - \theta)^2 \\ &= {\rm E}[\hat \theta^2] - 2 \theta {\rm E}[\hat \theta] + \theta^2 \\ &= {\rm E}[\hat \theta^2 - 2 \theta \hat \theta + \theta^2] \\ &= {\rm E}[(\hat\theta - \theta)^2] \\ &= {\rm MSE}[\hat \theta]. \end{align*}$$  If you want to prove it using the hint, the above computation should help you see how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the square,
$$
\begin{align}
(\hat\theta-\theta)^2&=(\hat\theta-{\rm E}[\hat\theta]+{\rm E}[\hat\theta]-\theta)^2\\
&=(\hat\theta-{\rm E}[\hat\theta])^2+({\rm E}[\hat\theta]-\theta)^2+2(\hat\theta-{\rm E}[\hat\theta])({\rm E}[\hat\theta]-\theta)
\end{align}
$$
and take expectation to get
$$
{\rm E}[(\hat\theta-\theta)^2]=\mathrm{V}(\hat\theta)+\mathrm{B}(\hat\theta)^2
$$
since
$$
{\rm E}[2(\hat\theta-{\rm E}[\hat\theta])({\rm E}[\hat\theta]-\theta)]=0.
$$

Comment: why $E[2(\hat{\theta} - E(\hat{\theta})(E[\hat{\theta}] - \hat{\theta})] = 0$ and are you claiming $V(\hat{\theta}) = (\hat{\theta} - E[\hat{\theta}])^2$? If so, why?

Comment: No, I am using that $\mathrm{V}(\hat\theta)={\rm E}[(\hat\theta-{\rm E}[\hat\theta])^2]$ by definition. And I am claiming that ${\rm E}[2(\hat\theta-{\rm E}[\hat\theta])({\rm E}[\hat\theta]-\theta)]=0$ since $2({\rm E}[\hat\theta]-\theta)$ is just a constant and ${\rm E}[(\hat\theta-{\rm E}[\hat\theta])]=0$.

Comment: why $E[(\hat{\theta} −E[\hat{\theta}])] = 0$?

Comment: The expecation is linear and hence..

Comment: could you specify it as I do not see it?

Comment: also, how can $E[(E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta)^2] = B(\hat{\theta})^2$ as I think it should be $(E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta)^2 = B(\hat{\theta})^2 $?

Comment: Because $({\rm E}[\hat\theta]-\theta)^2$ is constant so it is equal to its own expectation.

Comment: If you can't use linearity of the expectation to deduce that ${\rm E}[\hat\theta-{\rm E}[\hat\theta]]=0$, then you need to take a step back and realize why this is true. More generally, show that ${\rm E}[X-\mu]=0$ for any random variable with mean $\mu={\rm E}[X]$.

Comment: what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: The reasoning? It's a fundamental property that the expectation is linear. It must surely be stated in the textbook you're following.